# funcparserlib: unexpected result

Tags: python, parsing

I'm using `funcparserlib` for parsing.

I cannot ignore comments and thus have to check for comments after each
token. This is why I added a comment parser to each parser created with
`make_parser()`. To keep this example easy, the comment is mandatory and not
optional.

Concerning the example below I have two questions:

1. The output is

```
Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo')
Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment')
(Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo'), Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment'))
(Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo'), Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment'))
```

whereas I expected it to be either

```
(Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo'), Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment'))
(Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo'), Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment'))
(Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo'), Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment'))
```

or

```
Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo')
Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment')
Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo')
Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment')
Token(<TOK.foo: 1>, 'foo')
Token(<TOK.comment: 2>, '// comment')
```

How do I get the expected output?

2. Is there is a better way to check for comments after each token?

Here is the example source code:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from funcparserlib.lexer import make_tokenizer
from funcparserlib.parser import Parser, some

#
# lexer
#
class TOK (Enum):
    foo = auto()
    comment = auto()
    whitespace = auto()

tokenizer = make_tokenizer([
    (TOK.whitespace, (r'[ \n\r\t]+', )),
    (TOK.foo, (r'\bfoo\b', )),
    (TOK.comment, (r'//.*', )),
])

#
# parser
#
def make_parser (tok):
    @Parser
    def func (toks, state):
        p = (some (lambda t:t.type == tok) +
             some (lambda t:t.type == TOK.comment))
        return p.run(toks, state)
    return func

foo = make_parser (TOK.foo)

@Parser
def content_parser (toks, state):
    p = foo + foo + foo
    return p.run (toks, state)

#
# main
#
content = """
foo // comment
foo // comment
foo // comment
"""

token_stream = [tok for tok in tokenizer(content)
                if tok.type != TOK.whitespace]
result = content_parser.parse (token_stream)

for i in result:
    print(i.__repr__())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's best to pack the parser result into a `tuple` manually like this:

```
def make_parser (tok):
    @Parser
    def func (toks, state):
        p = (some (lambda t:t.type == tok) +
             some (lambda t:t.type == TOK.comment)) >> (lambda i: tuple(i))
        return p.run(toks, state)
    return func
```

Note: By default the parser result is packed into a `_Tuple` which actually `is` a `tuple`. But then function `magic()` inside `Parser.__add__()` does some magic stuff by repacking/unpacking the parser result if it is a `_Tuple`. By forcing the result to be packed into a `tuple` (with `>> (lambda i: tuple(i))` in the code above), function `magic()` will not touch it.